# How do I calculate execution time of Matlab Code for variable input?

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the execution time of Matlab code under the following conditions: I wrote a Matlab function named `somecode` which has an input variable `counter`. I want to calculate the execution time for each input value. Initially, `counter=20`, and the input of `somecode` is therefore 20. Then, `counter` is increased by 20 in every iteration, until it reaches 500. I want to know the time taken by `somecode` for every value of `counter` ( 20 to 500 ).
Where do I need to use the `tic`, `toc` commands?

```
counter=20;               
while (counter<=500)             
    somecode(counter);           
    counter=counter+20;           
end
```

Please suggest any solution. 
Thank You

Comment: `timeit` should be preferred if available in your matlab version, is it available?

Comment: i just checked its not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an initial idea, I would do something like this with a `for` loop. It's nothing fancy, but it should give an idea to the runtimes.

```
% Create a vector for the entries of counter and for the runtimes.
% (Make them column vectors for displaying with table)
big_counter = (20:20:500)';
somecode_times = zeros(size(big_counter));

% Loop over the entries of counter
for ii = 1:length(big_counter)
  counter = big_counter(ii);
  tic;
  somecode(counter);
  % Save the runtime to somecode_times
  somecode_times(ii) = toc;
end

% Display the times in a table by uncommenting 
%table(big_counter, somecode_times)
% Otherwise show the results side by side
display([big_counter, somecode_times])

plot(big_counter, somecode_times,'+-')
xlabel 'counter'
ylabel 'time'
title 'time taken to run somecode(counter)'
```

Example output:

```
   20.0000    0.0008
   40.0000    0.0017
   60.0000    0.0047
   80.0000    0.0072
  100.0000    0.0107
  120.0000    0.0186
  140.0000    0.0297
  160.0000    0.0496
  180.0000    0.0658
  200.0000    0.0949
  220.0000    0.1743
  240.0000    0.1734
  260.0000    0.2313
  280.0000    0.2767
  300.0000    0.3187
  320.0000    0.3959
  340.0000    0.4679
  360.0000    0.6698
  380.0000    0.7474
  400.0000    0.9920
  420.0000    0.9221
  440.0000    1.1148
  460.0000    1.2610
  480.0000    1.3960
  500.0000    1.6945
```

[image: Example output plot for SO code]

Comment: With `timeit` not being available I expect `table` is also not available. Better use a simple matrix at the end.

Comment: @Steve Thank You very much. Can You tell me how can I find mathematical equation between time and counter in following way : time= logarithm function of counter. ?

Comment: @user36036: that question goes by far beyond what can be answered in a comment. Just a introduction http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475803/how-can-i-find-which-function-corresponds-to-a-set-of-data-points